# How can i create Drag and Drop image functionality in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to create one puzzle which enables user to drag and drop images within in some boundary like list box or any other. Kindly help me what can i use and how. I am new to this.

Comment: Check this link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64595-7fed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_7.html) link.Hope it may help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Its working but it is for single image only how can I embed more than one image. I not getting any idea. Help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167715/flex-bitmapdata-from-multiple-images-drag-dropped